# Set as start page with full url in web config mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using set as sate as start page in webconfig and rout config

my web config code is

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="30" protection="All" />
```

And my Rout Config code

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");    
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Now I type The website url in http://epstechno.com/schoolbriefcase/ . It's redirect to the login page .But This time I want to go http://epstechno.com/schoolbriefcase/Account/Login Full url . Not want just http://epstechno.com/schoolbriefcase/

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");    
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{YourStartUpContollerName}/{Action(ByDefaultIndex)}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```